# How to get all Content files with CopyToOutputDirectory = Always?

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, build-automation, tfsbuild

Is there an easy way in MSBuild to get all `Content` files defined in a `*.csproj` file with the `CopyToOutputDirectory` set to `Always`? For some reason, my MSBuild script isn't copying these files to my output directory, so I'm trying to create a post-build target to manually move them.

EDIT: This is in VS 2008 with .NET 3.5

Comment: what is the Build Action for these files?

Comment: @devio The Build Action for all of these files is `Copy Always`.

Comment: Build Action and Copy To Output Directory are two different settings! is Build Action set to Content?

Comment: @devio Sorry, I misread your comment. Yes, Build Action is Content, and Copy to Output Directory is Copy Always.